# how do you describe a car's height?

Tags: adjectives

what is the adjective you use to describe the extent or degree of distance from the roof of a car to the ground

is it "a short car" or "a low car"?

and is it "a tall car" or "a high car", or maybe you use some other adjectives to describe it?

and by extension, can I apply to other objects as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "tall car" or a "high car" - both are used.

A "low car" is better than a "short car" since a short car is one that is short from front to back.

More often you see "a car with a high driving position" or "a car with a low ride" (the chassis is close to the ground).

On Eurotunnel, a "high car" is defined as being over 1.85m. Other cars are classed as "low cars".

So, by extension, you can say "a low table", "a high table" and so on and so forth. However people are usually "tall" or "short".

Comment: so by extension I can say "a low table" "a high table" so on and so forth? @james-k

Comment: And a car with "low clearance" has a small distance between the ground and the bottom of the car (such as sports cars), while "high clearance" describes off-road vehicles and trucks with a larger distance between the ground and the bottom of the car.

Comment: Yes, ground clearance, and riding low to the ground. But otherwise, tall or short is fine. https://carbiketech.com/ground-clearance/ I'm also finding ride height. A "high table" is actually a type of furniture, but you can also say a table is high. So, is a low table (coffee table). High off floor, low off the floor, too.

Comment: For 'table' specifically, because historically noble and/or rich people ate at an elevated table, 'high table' is still used to mean one where the people are selected or restricted

Answer (score 1):

OP asks

> ... and by extension, can I apply [the terms] to other objects as well?

It would be grammatical but not necessarily idiomatic to use "tall" and "low" of *anything and everything* that has height.

For example, you might well say "The club sandwich is rather a tall sandwich" or "a **high** sandwich" but you wouldn't really say "A grilled-cheese sandwich is a **low** sandwich"; and "a **short** sandwich" relates to its length not its height.

Comment: so how do you describe "a low sandwich" to other people that everyone can understand easily?

Comment: We don't typically describe normal sandwiches in terms of their height. If it's between two slices of bread and it's not piled high, it's just "a sandwich".

Comment: so I guess you can clarify by saying "sandwich of little height" if you really want to express it?

Comment: That would be grammatical but most strange.  :)  It would be "a sandwich with not much in it".

Comment: A flattish sandwich or a flat sandwich, like a panini.

Comment: (IME) sandwiches are often characterized as 'thick' or 'thin'. Marketers also like 'overstuffed' (but I have never seen 'understuffed').